# holoviews / bokeh import error

Tags: python, data-visualization, python-import, bokeh, holoviews

I'm working with

```
In [2]: bokeh.__version__
Out[2]: '0.12.1'

In [4]: holoviews.__version__
Out[4]: 1.8.4
```

The following import

```
from holoviews.plotting.bokeh import BokehRenderer
```

produces an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c53ae81a79e0> in <module>()
----> 1 from holoviews.plotting.bokeh import BokehRenderer

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/__init__.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from bokeh.palettes import all_palettes
      5 
      6 from ...core import (Store, Overlay, NdOverlay, Layout, AdjointLayout,

ImportError: cannot import name 'all_palettes'
```

It has worked before, and I can't trace what has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HoloViews 1.8.4 requires a recent version of bokeh with >=0.12.6 being recommended. I'd suggest upgrading with:

```
conda install -c bokeh bokeh=0.12.9
```

or

```
pip install bokeh
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. I thought I had the newest bokeh after running `pip3 install --upgrade bokeh`, but apparently a reinstall was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
pip install bokeh==0.12.15
pip install holoviews==1.10.4
```